# Are my recursion conditions right to compute binary tree height?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to know whether my code is right or wrong with your help, because sadly I can't run it to check.

There are no compile errors.  What I'm trying to do is to find the **height of a binary tree**. The tree does not have to be balanced, of course.

[Each node in Binary tree can have two nodes as children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)

```
public int height(RBNode t) {
  if (t == null)
  return 0;

  int heightLeft = height(t.left);
  int heightRight = height(t.right);

  if (heightLeft > heightRight) {
    return heightLeft + 1;
  } else {
    return (heightRight + 1);
  }
}
```

Do you think the recursion conditions are right? My friend claims that it will always return 0.

Comment: Small advice: You shouldn't mix code styles. Either you surround one line `if` blocks with curly braces or you don't. Everything else tends to confuse other readers of your code.

Comment: Why can you not run it yourself? Do you not have a computer to work on? If not, from where are you writing this, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really compact version:

```
public int height(RBNode t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: You can condense the code even more, but this makes it harder to understand and should not be used:
`return t == null ? 0 :  Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right)) + 1;`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: 
    if (t == null) { return -1; } 
?

Answer (score 5):

Looks fine to me, although I'd personally change the last bit to:

```
return Math.max(heightLeft, heightRight) + 1;
```

I'm concerned that you can't run it at all though... why can you not write unit tests around this? I'd be nervous of any code I can't test :)

Comment: @nfechner: Absolutely :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, as long as you pass in the head of the tree, it'll return the correct value. But it should have been easy to construct a test to validate this...

Answer (score 0):

In the code in the question, are we not getting height +1? the height is defined as 'length of the path from the root to the deepest node in the tree. A (rooted) tree with only one node (the root) has a depth of zero.'(wikipedia)

if in question's code if give the root to a tree with just 1 node it will give height as 1, which should infact be 0..

Please correct me if i am wrong somewhere..

Comment: Whether or not a tree of a single node (just the root) has length 1 or length 0 is something of a matter of interpretation.  Some people feel very strongly that the former is correct, and some the latter.